# Div with fixed position not shown in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-position

I have the following problem that a div with fixed position is shown in every browser (tested on Mac with Chrome, Firefox, Opera) but not in Safari.

I've done some research but couldn't figure out at all where the problem originates from.

[image: Screenshot of div (left Chrome & right Safari)]
<sub>Chrome (left) and Safari (right)</sub>

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#bewerber-tab").click(function() {
    jQuery("#bewerber-form").toggle("slide");
    return false;
  });
  jQuery("#bewerber-link").click(function() {
    jQuery("#bewerber-form").toggle("slide");
  });
  jQuery(document).click(function() {
    jQuery("#bewerber-form").hide("slide");
  });
});
```

```css
#bewerber {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}

#bewerber-tab {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-left: -50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#bewerber-form {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #000000;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bewerber">
  <div id="bewerber-form" style='display:none;'>
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="bewerber-tab">Bewerberbogen</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why the div with fixed position is working everywhere except for Safari browser?

Comment: I'm not able to try in Safari right now, but maybe it's a positioning problem. Add z-index to the `bewerber` div and see how it works...

Comment: I've already tested it with z-index but there was no change in Safari...